# Problem with booting from usb stick

Tags: boot, usb, hybrid-graphics

Currently I have Ubuntu installed on my HDD, and I want to install Windows on the same hdd. I have already seen this post [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows). I have created USB stick with Ubuntu on it using Unetbootin but when I try to boot from it, I get these options:

1. Try Ubuntu without installing
2. Install Ubuntu
3. OEM install
4. Check CD for errors

That is in UEFI mode (in boot menu there are two entries for my USB stick: with UEFI and without). In legacy mode there are some more, but they do not matter.

My problem is that I get black screen when I am trying to use Ubuntu without installing. I have two graphics cards: one from Nvidia and another from Intel (integrated to CPU). I think that the problem can be in this, however other systems (my current installed Ubuntu and Windows on other broken HDD, that is why I want to reinstall it) can be booted OK, without any problems.

Is there any way to choose graphic card that I want to use? Or should I write Ubuntu to USB stick in other way, without using Unetbootin?

Comment: Me thinks you're overcomplicating. If your Ubuntu has been installed in UEFI mode (it should be) then installing Windows in the same mode (it should be) is no problem. At UEFI settings make Ubuntu first boot priority again. The "repair" you're attempting is only applicable to legacy.

Comment: @CelticWarrior may be, but I don't want to have any risks. I want to make myself sure that I can restore GRUB in case it will be overwritten by Windows. And to do that, I will need working USB stick with Ubuntu or any other distro.

Comment: Do not use Unetbootin then, prefer MKUSB. You'll most likely need `nomodeset` either way if using the Nvidia card without the proprietary drivers installed. Better to just disable it at UEFI setting if all you need is to boot a live session to do some "repairs". Again, install everything properly and use the UEFI boot menu whenever needed. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: @CelticWarrior ok, I will reboot now and check if `nomodeset` instead of  `quiet splash` helps.

Comment: @CelticWarrior ok, you can see my answer, and today I'll install windows and say to you if I had to do "repairs".

Comment: @CelticWarrior firstly, I had to convert my hdd to GPT, which I've done. I've created EFI partition on disk, but while installing windows after it, I had the following error message: "Setup was unable to create a new system partition or locate an existing system partition. See the Setup log files for more information.". Windows created some partitions manually, and also there is first EFI that I've created manually. What can I do to fix that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When booting, I chose UEFI mode and edited `Try without installing` entry replacing `quiet splash` with `nomodeset`. That is for Nvidia, I am not sure about other graphic cards, but may be that will work.